# Reordenar lista a partir de un índice dado

Tags: python, lista

¿Existe algún método directo en python para reordenar una lista a través de un índice de la siguiente manera?:

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
index = 3
reordered_list = [3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con una lista se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```py
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
index = 3
reordered_list = my_list[index::-1] + my_list[index+1:]
print(reordered_list) # [3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Nota que está desaconsejado emplear "list" como nombre de una variable. La instrucción "list" tiene la función de crear una lista, y esto deja de funcionar al momento que hay una variable con el mismo nombre.

Aquí `my_list[index::-1]` empieza con el índice 'index' con pasos de `-1`, es decir al revés. Al dejar libre el segundo argumento en los colones cojo todo los elementos que hay hasta el principio. De manera similar, `my_list[index+1:]` empieza con `index+1` en pasos de `1` hasta el final de la lista. Sumar listas con `+` hace una concatenación de ambos.

Hay mas información sobre *slicing* por ejemplo en el [siguiente enlace](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/12/18/operaciones-cortar-arreglos-python/).

Answer (score 0):

No existe ninguna forma ya implementada de hacer esto directamente para `list`. Puedes implementarlo de todas formas usado rebanado:

```
def index_rot(lista: list, idx: int) -> list:
    l = len(lista)
    if not -l <= idx <= (l - 1):
        raise ValueError(f"{index} no es un índice válido para la lista de longitud {l}")
    return lista[::] if idx == -1 or idx == 0 else lista[idx::-1] + lista[idx + 1:]
```

Puedes usar cualquier índice válido para la lista, incluidos negativos:

```
l1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for index in range(-8, 8):
    print(f"{index_rot(l1, index)} ---> index: {index}")
```

> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] ---> index: -8
> [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] ---> index: -7
> [2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] ---> index: -6
> [3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7] ---> index: -5
> [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7] ---> index: -4
> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 7] ---> index: -3
> [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 7] ---> index: -2
> [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] ---> index: -1
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] ---> index: 0
> [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] ---> index: 1
> [2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] ---> index: 2
> [3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7] ---> index: 3
> [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 6, 7] ---> index: 4
> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 7] ---> index: 5
> [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 7] ---> index: 6
> [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] ---> index: 7
> ```

Si lo deseas, puedes implementar la función para que realize la oeración in-place:

```
def index_rot(lista: list, idx: int) -> None:
    l = len(lista)
    if not -l <= idx <= (l - 1):
        raise ValueError(f"{index} no es un índice válido para la lista de longitud {l}")
    if idx != -1 and idx != 0:
        lista[:idx + 1], lista[idx + 1:] = lista[idx::-1], lista[idx + 1:]
```

> ```
> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> index_rot(l, -5)
> print(l)
> [3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> ```